# JAVA: How to convert String ArrayList to Integer Arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

My question is -
how to convert a String ArrayList to an Integer ArrayList?

I have numbers with `°` behind them `EX: 352°`. If I put those into an Integer ArrayList, it won't recognize the numbers. To solve this, I put them into a String ArrayList and then they are recognized.

I want to convert that String Arraylist back to an Integer Arraylist. So how would I achieve that?

This is my code I have so far. I want to convert ArrayString to an Int Arraylist.

```
        // Read text in txt file.
    Scanner ReadFile = new Scanner(new File("F:\\test.txt"));

    // Creates an arraylist named ArrayString
    ArrayList<String> ArrayString = new ArrayList<String>();

    // This will add the text of the txt file to the arraylist.
    while (ReadFile.hasNextLine()) {

        ArrayString.add(ReadFile.nextLine());
    }

    ReadFile.close();


    // Displays the arraystring.
    System.out.println(ArrayString);
```

Thanks in advance

Diego

PS: Sorry if I am not completely clear, but English isn't my main language. Also I am pretty new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more lenient parsing process, you might consider using a regular expression.

**Note:** The following code is using Java 7 features (try-with-resources and diamond operator) to simplify the code while illustrating good coding practices (closing the Scanner). It also uses common naming convention of variables starting with lower-case, but you may of course use any convention you want).

This code is using an inline string instead of a file for two reasons: It shows that data being processed, and it can run as-is for testing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testdata = "55°\r\n" +
                      "bad line with no number\r\n" +
                      "Two numbers: 123   $78\r\n";
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayInt = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner readFile = new Scanner(testdata)) {
        Pattern digitsPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
            Matcher m = digitsPattern.matcher(readFile.nextLine());
            while (m.find())
                arrayInt.add(Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrayInt);
}
```

This will print:

```
[55, 123, 78]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace any character you want to ignore (in this case `°`) using `String.replaceAll`:

```
 "somestring°".replaceAll("°",""); // gives "sometring"
```

Or you could remove the last character using `String.substring`:

```
"somestring°".substring(0, "somestring".length() - 1); // gives "somestring"
```

One of those should work for your case.

Now all that's left is to parse the input on-the-fly using [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (ReadFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String input = ReadFile.nextLine();
    try {
        // try and parse a number from the input. Removes trailing `°`
        arrayInts.add(Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("°","")));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.err.println("'" + input + "' is not a number!");
    }
}
```

You can add your own handling to the case where the input is not an actual number.

Comment: Yes but if i do this it says that it is not a number. Because they have ° behind it so its 273° 250° and it says these are not numbers but i'm trying to go from 273° to int arraylist..

Comment: What do you mean with somestring with what do i need to replace it? Sorry if sound stupid :/

Comment: Alright it deleted the ° now but i still get the is not a number message. My Output is now: '' is not a number!
[273, 183, 182, 140]

Comment: Show an example of the input

Comment: 273°
183°
182°
140°

Do you mean this?

Comment: This is a single line? if so you want to split it first. I was under the impression your line contains a single value.

Comment: No they're multiple lines. Like 273° then enter and then 183°

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a new instance of an ArrayList typed with the Integer wrapper class and give it the same size buffer as the String list:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(ArrayString.size());
```

And then iterate through Arraystring assigning the values over from one to the other by using a parsing method in the wrapper class

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayString.size(); i++) {
    myList.add(Integer.parseInt(ArrayString.get(i)));

}
```